# How works Principled Volume?

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes, volumetrics

I created a Geometry Nodes (GN) node tree that simulates the smoke trail from a missile.

The simulation of fire from the nozzle is done with emission, which is limited by a gradient. Its position is linked to the missile, which moves with the constraint *Follow Path* along the same curve on which the smoke is "pulled".

Then I wanted to get rid of constraint, so I joined the geometry of the missile with the smoke, stored the position of the missile to the attribute, and used it in shader nodes. But when I turn the smoke mesh into a volumetric, the attribute is "nulled", because you can't write an attribute on a volumetric.

Here the question arises - how do shader nodes calculate the missile position for volume and is it possible to repeat it somehow with GN?

[image]

[image]

[image]

("Missile pos" empty created for fast switch between attribute and "old" shader in shader nodes)

Comment: I don't know how to solve it actually, but I guess the problem here is the attribute data you want to store has to be stored somewhere in the geometry. In the _Store Named Attribute_ you have several domains to choose from: _Point_, _Edge_, _Face_, _Face Corner_, _Spline_ and _Instance_. But the _Geometry_ you plug in there to store the data is a _Volume Grid_. Which means, there is no geometry on which you store the information and therefore you cannot read it with an _Attribute_ node in the shader.

Comment: ...so actually the title of your question is very misleading. It has nothing to do with how the _Principled Volume_ shader works, more with how attributes are stored in _Geometry Nodes_.

Comment: I wrote that I understand that the shader breaks because the attribute cannot be written to the volume field. And my question is directly related to the topic title. How does Principled Volume work, how does it calculate gradient position if volume cannot have an attribute? Or blender developers just forgot to add volume type to store attribute node, and actually volume has attributes? Because otherwise how does texture coordinate calculate gradient for volume?

Comment: A volume grid in _Geometry Nodes_ is as the name says, a grid. You define the resolution etc. similar as you have to define a resolution for a smoke simulation for example. You define voxels in which density information is stored. Shaders (not only the _Principled Volume_) work different. A simple linear gradient for example can go from 0 at the left to 1 at the right side. You can zoom in anywhere inbetween and it goes seamless from black to white (mathematically speaking, limited only by the capabilities of the colorspace and/or float precision). Voxels are discrete locations, not functions.